# Question re: FailedInserts PCollection / Beam 2.45 versus 2.49 behavior confirmation

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Context: [GitHub Issue 26853](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/26853)

I have a question around the above referenced feature request and differences in `Beam 2.45 versus 2.49`.

In case the `FailedInserts PCollection` is not consumed, `BigQueryIO` will silently drop records.This is probably working as intended, but I believe we should use a counter to expose this situation to users."

It looks like `FailedInserts PCollection` is used to address the schema mismatch, i.e. when the record and the provided schema doesn’t match and caused the conversion method to throw exception, that record will be output to `FailedInserts`.

In `Beam 2.45.0`, the `FailedInserts PCollection` will simply be Flattened and thrown away; In `Beam 2.49.0`, those `FailedInserts PCollection` will still be Flattened and thrown away, but Beam updates a counter to show how many failed conversions happened.

Can someone help confirm the following two points?

1. The `FailedInserts PCollection` is used to only collect records that have schema mismatch in both `Beam 2.45.0 and Beam 2.49.0`;
2. When `FailedInserts PCollection` is not null, both `Beam 2.45.0 and Beam 2.49.0` will throw those records away; The only difference is that `Beam 2.49.0` will update a counter while `Beam 2.45.0` has no such counter.

Looking to confirm whether `FailedInserts PCollection` result(s) get thrown away in both `2.45 and 2.49`

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Yes. I will not call it throw away. User's code need to handle how to process this failed PCollection, for examples, using another sink.

For BigQuery IO, given the fast development on both Beam and BigQuery, it is highly recommended to always use the latest Beam.